# Error While Building IOS App Intel XDK

Tags: ios, cordova, provisioning-profile, intel-xdk

I am building an Intel XDK Cordova app. I am getting the following error:

**Error:** Your mobile provisioning profile does not match your selected certificate. Please see the Intel XDK FAQs for information on how to fix this.

**Here is the build log:**

Building a Cordova 5.4.1 application.

Using platform cordova-ios 4.0.1.

The application name is "Draw My Tune"

The package name is "com.aworld.drawmytune"

Plugin "cordova-plugin-file" (4.1.0) installed.

Plugin "cordova-plugin-media" (2.2.0) installed.

-----End of log-----

Error: Your mobile provisioning profile does not match your selected certificate. Please see the Intel XDK FAQs for information on how to fix this.

I've made a previous app and there were no problems. Now, I have this. Does anybody see why this is occurring? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new set of provisioning files and certs. That will generally fix the problem.